# Error: Cannot find module 'neo4j-driver/types/v1'

Tags: node.js, neo4j, webpack-4

The error message:

> Cannot find module 'neo4j-driver/types/v1'

is generated in `internal/modules/cjs/loader.js` when trying to run my node server.

The following code is my neo4j import statements

```
import Config from "../../../utilities/Config"

const neo4j = require('neo4j-driver').v1;
const driver = neo4j.driver(Config.bolt, 
    neo4j.auth.basic(Config.neoUsername, Config.neoPassword));

export function createSession() {
    return driver.session()
}

export function closeDriver() {
    driver.close();
}
```

My package.json file dependencies are:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.23.3",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.5",
    "babel-plugin-transform-async-to-generator": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy": "^1.3.5",
    "babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-react-constant-elements": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-react-remove-prop-types": "^0.4.18",
    "babel-plugin-transform-regenerator": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-register": "6.26.0",
    "babel-runtime": "^6.26.0",
    "brotli-gzip-webpack-plugin": "^0.5.0",
    "chunk-manifest-webpack-plugin": "^1.1.2",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^0.1.19",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.11",
    "cssnano": "^4.1.7",
    "cssnano-preset-default": "^4.0.5",
    "csv-loader": "^3.0.2",
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "file-loader": "^1.1.11",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "image-webpack-loader": "^4.4.0",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.3",
    "postcss-cssnext": "3.1.0",
    "postcss-loader": "^3.0.0",
    "postcss-nested": "^4.1.0",
    "progress-bar-webpack-plugin": "^1.11.0",
    "react-hot-loader": "^4.3.12",
    "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^2.0.1",
    "url-loader": "^1.1.2",
    "webpack": "^4.20.2",
    "webpack-chunk-hash": "^0.6.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.2",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^3.4.0",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.24.3",
    "webpack-merge": "^4.1.4",
    "webpack-node-externals": "^1.7.2",
    "xml-loader": "^1.2.1"
},
"dependencies": {
    "apollo-boost": "^0.1.20",
    "apollo-client": "^2.4.5",
    "apollo-engine": "^1.1.2",
    "apollo-errors": "^1.9.0",
    "apollo-server-express": "^1.4.0",
    "argon2": "^0.19.3",
    "axios": "0.18.0",
    "bcrypt-nodejs": "0.0.3",
    "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
    "boxen": "^2.0.0",
    "compression": "^1.7.3",
    "connect-mongo": "^2.0.1",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.3",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.5.3",
    "cors": "^2.8.4",
    "cross-env": "^5.2.0",
    "crypto": "^1.0.1",
    "express-graphql": "^0.6.12",
    "express-session": "^1.15.6",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.0-beta.0",
    "graphql": "^0.13.2",
    "graphql-date": "^1.0.3",
    "graphql-tag": "^2.10.0",
    "graphql-tools": "^2.24.0",
    "helmet": "^3.14.0",
    "http": "0.0.0",
    "https": "^1.0.0",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "^2.2.1",
    "isomorphic-style-loader": "^4.0.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.3.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^0.4.4",
    "moment": "^2.22.2",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.21",
    "mongoose": "^5.3.2",
    "neo4j-driver": "^1.7.1",
    "node-fetch": "^2.2.0",
    "node-pre-gyp": "^0.11.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.9.3",
    "node-uuid": "^1.4.8",
    "nodemailer": "^4.6.8",
    "opn": "^5.4.0",
    "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.3",
    "passport": "^0.4.0",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.2",
    "qrcode": "^1.3.0",
    "react": "^16.7.0-alpha",
    "react-apollo": "^2.2.4",
    "react-dom": "^16.7.0-alpha",
    "react-helmet": "^5.2.0",
    "react-intl-universal": "^1.15.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "recompose": "^0.30.0",
    "regenerator-runtime": "^0.11.1",
    "semantic-ui-react": "^0.83.0",
    "serve-favicon": "^2.5.0",
    "speakeasy": "^2.0.0",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^3.0.3",
    "webpack-config": "^7.5.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.9",
    "webpack-manifest-plugin": "^2.0.4",
    "whatwg-fetch": "^3.0.0",
    "yn": "^2.0.0"
}
```

The files are built with Webpack 4.20.2
I am running on node v10.13.0 and have tried 11.0.0

I have tried deleting the node_modules and installing again.  I have also tried version 1.6.3 of the "neo4j-driver" package but always get the same error.

The project connects to a grapheneDB hosted neo4j database via the bolt protocol.  My implementation appears to be that outlined on the neo4j website.

I am a novice node.js developer but have had this running in the past on my previous MacBook. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Is `/node_modules/` in the same directory as your `node.js` server code?  That was my problem... I installed `neo4j-driver` in the `/web` directory...it should be one level higher.

Answer (score 0):

I built the project and run the server on a windows laptop and got the same error. 
It made me go back to the code and deep in the error trace it became obvious . 
The error was actually originating from a different file than I thought.  The error was due to an errant reference to the neo4j session object.  Once this was corrected everything worked.